# Spring batch Save skipped reader lines in rejection file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to rewrite skipped reader lines in output rejection file, thanks.

My code :

```
public class JobPerson {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;


    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Person> itemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("user.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(";") {{
                setNames(new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "age" });
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                setTargetType(Person.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }



    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            int i=0;
            for (Person item : items) {
                i++;

                System.out.println(i+". Nom = " + item.getFirstName()+". Prenom = " + item.getLastName());
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Person, Person> itemProcessor() {
        return item -> {
            String stritem=item.toString();
            String[] splitArray = stritem.split(";"); // tableau de chaînes
            int lineData = splitArray.length;
            //if (lineData<2)

            if (item.equals("Eric")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wanted!");
            }
            return item;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return steps.get("step")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(5)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .processor(itemProcessor())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(IllegalArgumentException.class)
                .skipLimit(100)
                .listener(new MySkipListener())
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    public static class MySkipListener implements SkipListener<Person, Person> {

        @Override
        public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("On Skip in Read Error : " + t.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipInWrite(Person item, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Item " + item + " was skipped due to: " + t.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipInProcess(Person item, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Item " + item + " was skipped due to: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Lines to rewrite( lines in red):

[image: lines writing with red]

=> On Skip in Read Error : Parsing error at line: 2 in resource=[class path resource [user.csv]], input=[Eric;Bonneton;]
On Skip in Read Error : Parsing error at line: 3 in resource=[class path resource [user.csv]], input=[sdqsdqs;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the error is occurring during reading, with a [`FlatFileParseException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileParseException.html) exception. This exception gives you the line number and the raw input line that was skipped.

So your skip listener can be something like:

```
public static class MySkipListener implements SkipListener<Person, Person> {

    private FileWriter fileWriter;

    public MySkipListener(File file) throws IOException {
        this.fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instanceof FlatFileParseException) {
            FlatFileParseException flatFileParseException = (FlatFileParseException) throwable;
            try {
                fileWriter.write(flatFileParseException.getInput());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to write skipped line to error file");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(Person item, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Item " + item + " was skipped due to: " + t.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(Person item, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Item " + item + " was skipped due to: " + t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then you can configure the listener in your step with the file you want to write skipped lines to at construction time. You would also need to declare `FlatFileParseException` as a skippable exception.

Hope this helps.