# How to handle exception in spring batch for CSV -> DB?

Tags: spring-batch

I come across this link - [How to handle exception and skip the wrong csv line as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347349/how-to-handle-exception-and-skip-the-wrong-csv-line-as-well)

The answer is marked as answered but don't understand it clearly.

I have the similar situation

```
a. processing csv file - let's say 100 records
b. first 10 are valid, next 10 are invalid data, next 10 are 
   valid data but business errors, next 10 are no business 
   error but DB size limit error
```

How to generate one single error csv file in all these cases where the error csv file should have the each csv row data which got failed, reason as one column, file name as another column, row number etc.,

I don't find a good example with respect to this context.

Can someone help me with one or explain the above link to handle the case?

General Link for Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/1.1.x/spring-batch-docs/reference/html/execution.html

Thanks.

Comment: What is not clear in the answer? The sample in the question declares `FlatFileParseException` as a skippable exception. Now Spring Batch provides an API that you can implement to intercept such exception while reading lines from the file. If you implement this interface and write error in a file, you would have a file with error at the end of you job. The same mechanism can be used for error happening during processing or writing.

Comment: Do we need to use @StepScope as the same file should be shared for the entire job? Can we use a separate writer to write this? How to have a unique writer to write i.e open, append the log and close the file.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Please let me know your comments

Comment: The step or job scope is needed for late binding of job parameters and context attributes at runtime. You need a file writer in your skip listener since you are going to write errors in a different file. It is up to you to handle the lifecycle of this writer. One way to do that is to make the skip listener implement `StepExecutionListener`, which allows you to open the writer in `StepExecutionListener#beforeStep` and close it in `StepExecutionListener#afterStep`. You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54926176/5019386. You can adapt it as described previously.

Comment: Is it not a overhead to open and close a writer when we deal with an error file say of size 200 MB? Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: No, with the `StepExecutionListener`, you would open the file only once before the step starts, and you close it when the step has finished.

Comment: so if we specify chunk size, then it would open and end every time. am i right?

Comment: also, what would happen if we don't specify any batch size or chunk size.

Comment: `StepExecutionListener` methods are executed only once, one before the step and after the step. Do not confuse this with `ChunkListener`, where methods are called for each chunk. For you use case, the file would be opened/closed only once. For chunk size, there is no default value. You either need to provide it or provide a custom `CompletionPolicy` (See `SimpleStepBuilder#chunk()` methods).

Comment: I want to write each line which got error in the csv file. All the lines needs to be written